# Linearize an expression syntax tree

Tags: data-structures, ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree

I defined a recursive type like this

```
type t = | Param of int | Add of t * t
```

and it allows me to write symbolic expressions like this

```
let x = Param(1)
let y = Param(2)
let z = Add(x, y)
# z;;
- : t = Add (Param 1, Param 2)
```

or something slightly more complex

```
let rec fib n x y = match n with
  | 0 -> (x, y)
  | _ -> (fib (n - 1) y (Add(x, y)))      
let z5 = fib 5 x y
# z5;;
- : t * t =
(Add (Add (Param 2, Add (Param 1, Param 2)),
  Add (Add (Param 1, Param 2), Add (Param 2, Add (Param 1, Param 2)))),                                                         
 Add (Add (Add (Param 1, Param 2), Add (Param 2, Add (Param 1, Param 2))),                                                       
  Add (Add (Param 2, Add (Param 1, Param 2)),
   Add (Add (Param 1, Param 2), Add (Param 2, Add (Param 1, Param 2))))))
```

Now I want to convert this recursive thing into a linear form in which each unique Param and Add wold appears only once -- something like this:

```
(Step 0, (Param 1))
(Step 1, (Param 2))
(Step 2, (Add (Step 0, Step 1))
(Step 3, (Add (Step 1, Step 2))
(Step 4, (Add (Step 2, Step 3))
...
```

What is this transformation called? And how could it be implemented?

Answer (score 4):

I usually call it flattening or unfolding, some other common names (that are sometimes too specific) are [three address code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-address_code) or [A-normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-normal_form).

It is probably more natural to represent steps with assignments to variables, rather that with the `Step` notion, e.g.,

```
type var = int
type const = int
type stmt = Set var * const
type expr = Cst of int | Var of int | Add of expr * expr | ...
```

So that your flattened fib will look like

```
Set (0, (Add (Cst 1, Cst 2)))
Set (1, (Add (Cst 2, Var 0)))
Set (2, (Add (Var 0, Var 1)))
...
```

The flattening itself is quite easy to implement using a recursive function that has type `int -> expr -> stmt list -> int * expr * stmt list`, e.g., (untested),

```
let rec flatten v exprs stmts = match expr with
  | Cst _ | Var _ as expr -> v,expr,stmts
  | Add (x,y) -> 
    let v,x,stmts = flatten v x stmts in
    let v,y,stmts = flatten v x stmts in
    v+1,Var (v+1),(Set (v+1,Add(x,y)) :: stmts)
```

The `v` parameter is the fresh generator for variable names (which we represent just with integers).

Besides, if you would like to see how flattening works in real-world AST, here is [an example](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/pull/1332).

## Implementing hash-consing and flattening

First we need to define a hash-consed representation of our AST, e.g.,

```
type exp = Cst of int | Ref of int | Add of hexp * hexp
and hexp = {ref : int; exp : exp}
```

We index each hash-consed expression with a unique ordinal so that physically equal expressions will have the same `ref` number. We need this in order to be able to store expressions in ordered data structures like maps and sets (OCaml doesn't allow us to order values by their physical address, and it makes sense, since OCaml uses generational GC so the addresses of values change over time).

Now, let's write the `hashcons` function that will hash-cons an expression, e.g.,

```
let hashes = Hashtbl.create 100
let hashcons exp =
  match Hashtbl.find_opt hashes exp with
  | None ->
    let ref = Hashtbl.length hashes + 1 in
    Hashtbl.add hashes exp ref;
    {ref; exp}
  | Some ref -> {ref; exp}
```

Now we can write our fib function that uses the hashconsed representation,

```
let rec fib n x y = match n with
  | 0 -> (x, y)
  | _ -> fib (n - 1) y (hashcons (Add (x, y)))

let x = hashcons@@Cst 1
let y = hashcons@@Cst 2
let _,z = fib 999 x y
```

No big changes. Now, let's write the flatten function. But before that we need some representation for the program,

```
module Program = Map.Make(Int)

let set id x = Program.update id (function
    | None -> Some x
    | x -> x)

let rec get ref prog = match Program.find_opt ref prog with
  | None -> None
  | Some _ -> Some {ref; exp = Ref ref}

let (++) exp prog = {ref=exp.ref; exp=Ref exp.ref},
                    set exp.ref exp prog
```

Our program is a mapping from reference number (which acts both like a variable name and the place where variable is defined - we have a built-in SSA property in our representation), and finally, our flatten function is,

```
let unify {ref} exp prog =
  {ref; exp=Ref ref},
  set ref {ref; exp} prog

let rec flatten input prog =
  match get input.ref prog with
  | Some exp -> exp,prog
  | None -> match input.exp with
    | Cst _ | Ref _ -> input ++ prog
    | Add (x,y) ->
      let x,prog = flatten x prog in
      let y,prog = flatten y prog in
      unify input (Add (x,y)) prog
```

It is linear, because when we flatten a complex expression we use `unify` and store the flattened form of that expression under its id. So that the next time we see the same complex expression, we can easily extract its already flattened version from the program, using the integer key for lookup.

And the output is,

```
# let p = snd@@flatten z Program.empty
val p : hexp Program.t = <abstr>
# print_program p;;
#1 := 1
#2 := 2
#3 := #1 + #2
#4 := #2 + #3
#5 := #3 + #4
#6 := #4 + #5
<snip>
#1001 := #999 + #1000
- : unit = ()
```

where the `print_program` function is defined as,

```
let rec pp_exp ppf {exp} = match exp with
  | Cst x -> Format.fprintf ppf "%d" x
  | Ref x -> Format.fprintf ppf "#%d" x
  | Add (x,y) -> Format.fprintf ppf "%a + %a" pp_exp x pp_exp y

let print_program prog =
  Program.to_seq prog |>
  Seq.iter @@ fun (id,exp) ->
  Format.printf "#%d := %a@\n" id pp_exp exp
```

The flattening function works extremely fast, but as always it is not for free. The hash-consed version of `fib` is now much slower, as we have to hash-cons each expression and during it we have to lookup into a hash table and compare huge values structurally. The `fib` function is not exploiting the hash-consed representation of the expressions and it is possible to write a more efficient `fib` function.

Comment: Thank you for an answer. I tried to implement a recursion similar to 'flatten' example , and as I can see it will recurse into each branch of add, even for Add(x,x) where both arguments are the same. This leads to a very long expression list even for small inputs like (fib 20). What I would like to do is to represent each unique expression exactly once in the final sequence, and I couldn't find a way to do it efficiently.

Comment: Yes, this brings us to another concept, called [Hash consing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing)

Comment: It appears that Ocaml internally shares memory representation of 'x' for Add(x,x) so values like fib (99000) take linear memory and don't blow up exponentially: I wonder if there is a way to exploit this representation and make flattening linear or almost linear in run time (for well-constructed expressions)

Comment: Exploit no, but you can reify physical equality into an ordinal number so that you can store physically equal expressions in ordered data structures. Let me add some examples to the answer.